How to handle multi-repo cross-cutting concerns
I have an application that is a UI, an API, and a backing db for the API. All three are in different repos.
The state of each is (typically) tightly-bound to the others, i.e., if I make a change in the UI, it generally needs a change in the API, and that generally needs a change in the db schema.
My problem is that, given a commit id in one repo, there's no way to know what commit in the other repos is compatible. Is there a Git-based solution to this?
I've considered tagging, but that relies on the developers getting it right.

[tag:repo], https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450601/what-is-repo-and-why-does-google-use-it

That seems to be the start of the art for this problem. If you can post that as an answer, I'll accept it.
